# Visually show how the effect of one regressor diminishes the effect and significance of another

Tags: r, regression

I originally asked this question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76200571/visually-show-how-the-effect-of-one-regressor-diminishes-the-effect-and-signific), but was advised to move it to Cross Validated for a more appropriate place to have this discussion.

A commenter pointed out that my situation looks like it could be an example of the [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox). While this seems fitting based on the description that "a trend appears in several groups of data but disappears or reverses when the groups are combined", it does not fully explain the phenomenon. To me it seems like the graphs on the Simpson's Paradox page are illustrating an interaction effect, not the impact of controlling for another variable without interaction effects.

I would really appreciate an answer that can also shed some light on what might be going on mathematically as my statistical understanding about what it means to control for a variable and what can cause confounding effects is quite limited. I apologize if because of my lack of knowledge, my question is not as precise as it could be.

My current explanation/idea is that because the effect size of X1 on Y is quite small, adding an even only mildly correlated additional variable will decrease its effect size and significance greatly, to the point where it is no longer significant.

Below is my question.

---

After fitting my regression models, I found that the effect size and significance of one predictor is greatly diminished once I introduce another, dichotomous variable with a strong effect on the response variable. My interpretation is that the new variable's strong effect "overshadows" the one of the other variable. Based on correlation and VIFs, there don't seem to be any multicollinearity issues.

Assuming my interpretation is correct, how could I visually show how the inclusion of the second variable decreases the effect size and significance of the other variable? I thought about doing a scatter plot, but I think it only shows the strong effect of the new variable, not how the new variable influences the old one. What kind of visualization would be useful here? The goal is not to diagnose anything or to necessarily generate additional insight, but rather to make the regression results more intuitive for the reader of my analysis.

I hope that my question is succinct enough to be answered. I realize that it rests on the assumption that my interpretation of my regression is correct. If you have any other feedback aside from what kind of plot would be the best to do what I want, do share it. Thank you!

These are the regression results.

```
> stargazer(m1,m2,type="text")

==============================================
                      Dependent variable:     
                  ----------------------------
                               Y              
                       (1)            (2)     
----------------------------------------------
X1                   -0.012**       -0.006    
                     (0.005)        (0.005)   
                                              
X2                                 0.750***   
                                    (0.132)   
                                              
Constant             1.438***      1.074***   
                     (0.094)        (0.122)   
                                              
----------------------------------------------
Observations            56            56      
Log Likelihood       -133.332      -116.022   
Akaike Inf. Crit.    270.664        238.044   
==============================================
Note:              *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

This is the plot I made which I am not satisfied with yet.
[image]

Below is the data and code that I am working with.

```
#devtools::install_github("cmartin/ggConvexHull")
library(ggConvexHull)
library(ggplot2)
library(stargazer)
library(car)

# define data
df <- structure(list(Y = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 
                           6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
                           8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
                           3L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L), 
                     X1 = c(-35, -16, -23, -37, -6, -11, -18, -25, -26, -4, -16, 
                            -26, -13, -29, -33, -1, -6, -2, -28, -5, -1, -4, -2, -11, 
                            -38, -13, -16, -3, -1, -2, -10, -6, -12, -8, -9, -1, -4, 
                            -2, -1, -30, -7, -3, -18, -32, -32, -6, -6, -9, -8, -3, -3, 
                            -7, -9, -5, -4, -9), 
                     X2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                            0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                            0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                            1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -56L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
                )


# create glms
m1 <- glm(Y ~ X1, data=df, family="poisson")
m2 <- glm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data=df, family="poisson")

# there is some correlation
cor(df$X1, df$X2)

# but vifs look okay
vif(m2)

# results show that X1 becomes insignificant when X2 is added
stargazer(m1,m2,type="text")

# plot shows the effect of X2 clearly
# but can it also show the decline in the effect and significance of X1?
p <- ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x=X1, y=Y, color=factor(X2), shape=factor(X2)),
              size=4, alpha=.6, width=0.2, height=0.2) +
  geom_convexhull(aes(x=X1, y=Y, fill=factor(X2)),
                  alpha=.2)
p
```

Comment: Welcome to CV. Because these issues of how including or removing variables in multiple regressions affect all parameter estimates and collinearity are well covered here, the part of this question worth focusing on is the visualization. For a binary variable, a standard method is to facet the scatterplot. Are you familiar with [added variable plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22added+variable+plot%22)? BTW, inspecting correlations and VIFs may be helpful but is not adequate.  A close inspection of condition indices *ala* Belsley, Kuh, & Welsh can be worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful pointers! I am familiar with faceting by using `facet_grid(var1 ~ var2)` or the like, but I haven't heard of added variable plots before. I briefly looked into them and it seems like this is a plot where every facet shows one of the independent variables of the model on the x-axis and displays the fitted response variables on the y-axis alongside a regression line through the fitted values. I am not completely sure yet how such a plot would help me visualize the effect of X2's inclusion in the model, however.

Comment: @whuber _(cont)_ In the book you mentioned, do you recommend a specific passage to read or technique to apply in order to better assess whether there might be (multi)collinearity issues with my models?

Comment: All of Chapter 3, *Detecting and Assessing Collinearity,* followed by studying some of the examples in Chapter 4, *Applications and Remedies.*  As I recall, Chapter 3 is independent of the preceding chapters, so you can start directly in on it.  Chapter 4 will be harder to read without at least reviewing the previous chapters in detecting influential data.  Base `R` software provides fundamental capabilities in its `svd` and `influence` functions.

Comment: AVP plots were developed *specifically* to assess the effects of including one more variable in a regression.

Comment: I see, it seems like I misunderstood how this type of plot works. I managed to produce some added variable plots with `car::avPlots(m2)`. As expected, the slope of the regression line for `X1 | others` is going down and `X2 | others` up. Compared to `avPlots(m1)`, the slope for X1 is much flatter, reflecting the difference in effect sizes of X1 between the two models. I have just two questions based on this: (1) How could I show that not only the effect size but also the significance has changed of X1? Is there a way to convey visually _how_ this change occured (e.g. correlation with X2)?

Comment: (cont'd from above) (2) Is it appropriate that all lines are straight despite having used a GLM? As far as my understanding goes, the line should be at least a bit curved due to the log link function. `car::avPlots()` does support glms and lms according to the documentation, so maybe the function already takes this into account.

Comment: You should consult the docs and code for `car` to answer those questions.  One way (perhaps the commonest way) to display the significance of any slope is to plot a two-sided confidence band around the line.